# WCF InvalidOperationException: A binding instance has already been associated to listen URI

Tags: wcf

I'm a beginner of WCF and I'm studying in Essential WCF.

I encountered a problem when using ServiceContract NameSpace and Name.
when I run the code, I catch a bellow InvalidOperationException. But I couldn't understand clearly.

*A binding instance has already been associated to listen URI 'http://localhost:8080/NamespaceChange01'. If two endpoints want to share the same ListenUri, they must also share the same binding object instance. The two conflicting endpoints were either specified in AddServiceEndpoint() calls, in a config file, or a combination of AddServiceEndpoint() and config.*

Does anyone knows how to avide the InvalidOperationException ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace NamespaceChange01
{

    [ServiceContract(Name = "MyServiceName", Namespace = "http://ServiceNamespace")]
    public interface IBurgerMaster
    {
        [return: MessageParameter(Name = "myOutput")]
        [OperationContract(Name = "OperationName", Action = "OperationAction", ReplyAction = "ReplyActionName")]
        double GetStockPrice(string ticker);
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(Namespace = "http://MyService")]
    public class BurgerMaster : IBurgerMaster
    {

        public double GetStockPrice(string ticker)
        {
            return 100.99;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(BurgerMaster));
            host.Open();
            Console.ReadLine();
            host.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

- app.config

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <services>
        <service name="NamespaceChange01.BurgerMaster" behaviorConfiguration="mexServiceBehavior">
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/NamespaceChange01"/>
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
          <endpoint name="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="NamespaceChange01.IBurgerMaster"/>
          <endpoint name="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
      </services>
      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="mexServiceBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
  </configuration>
  ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Two endpoints (basic and mex) couldn't be on the same address. Add some specific address for one of them (or for both ones).

For example:

```
<endpoint name="mex" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

You're missing the **address** attribute from your metadata endpoint:

```
<endpoint name="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" address="mex" />
```

Without it WCF thinks you want to host the mex endpoint at the same address.

Comment: client application is using mexHttpsBinding and server using wsHttpsBinding ,i am also getting same error "Client and service binding mismatch"

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I recently had a very similar issue and google got me here plus I have a different potential solution:

By having a completely missing `service` tag for the service in question and when having a HTTP and HTTPS bindings for it in IIS, I ran into the exact same error message described.

Naturally, adding the `service` tag rectified the issue. Interestingly, deleting the HTTPS binding in IIS made the HTTP version usable (although that was obviously not desirable).

Answer (score -2):

While creating your service class, why did you mark it with ServiceContract attribute as your code says?

```
[ServiceBehavior(Namespace = "http://MyService")]
public class BurgerMaster : IBurgerMaster
```

Please remove that one and try again.

Comment: -1 This is incorrect - the OP's code is perfectly valid. It is the config which is incorrect