# A binding instance has already been associated to listen ''

Tags: wcf, rest

have WCF REST service that I’m trying to host in IIS 7 with SSL. Everything works fine as long as we DO NOT enable SSL in IIS.

As soon as I enable SSL in IIS and update configuration file  as . And then I browse service in IE. I get the error blow.

A binding instance has already been associated to listen URI 'https://machinename.mydomain.com/Service1/'. If two endpoints want to share the same ListenUri, they must also share the same binding object instance. The two conflicting endpoints were either specified in AddServiceEndpoint() calls, in a config file, or a combination of AddServiceEndpoint() and config.

Here is the service settings in configuration file.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
  <service name="ServiceGateway.Service1">
    <endpoint address=""
              contract="MyDomain.Services.ServiceGateway.Servie1"
              binding="webHttpBinding" />
  </service>
 </services>
 <bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding>
      <security mode="Transport"/>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>      
 </bindings>    
 <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
 <standardEndpoints>
   <webHttpEndpoint>        
     <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true"   automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
   </webHttpEndpoint>
 </standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Here is the code that executes at startup in Global.asax file

```
   public class Global : HttpApplication
   {
     public void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute(string.Empty, 
                      new WebServiceHostFactory(), 
                      typeof(Service1)));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506107/wcf-invalidoperationexception-a-binding-instance-has-already-been-associated-to

Comment: Could be an issue with a Framework 4.5 Install see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2805226 and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2805227