# System.InvalidOperationException: 'A binding instance has already been associated to listen

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I just started WCF for a project and it is showing the following exception, however I found some Question  related to this problem but I am not able to found in my code, here I am putting my code, please look and suggest the best solution for my code.

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="CompanyService.CompanyService" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="CompanyService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="CompanyService.ICompanyPublicService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="CompanyService" binding="netHttpBinding" contract="CompanyService.ICompanyConfidentialService"></endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/"/>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8091/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Here below is the error exception:

```
'A binding instance has already been associated to listen URI 'http://localhost:8080/CompanyService'. If two endpoints want to share the same ListenUri, they must also share the same binding object instance. The two conflicting endpoints were either specified in AddServiceEndpoint() calls, in a config file, or a combination of AddServiceEndpoint() and config. '
```

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506107/wcf-invalidoperationexception-a-binding-instance-has-already-been-associated-to). It seems like you're having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the name of the endpoint address:

```
    <services>
      <service name="CompanyService.CompanyService" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="CompanyService01" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="CompanyService.ICompanyPublicService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="CompanyService02" binding="netHttpBinding" contract="CompanyService.ICompanyConfidentialService"></endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/"/>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8091/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
```